# Is it possible to maintain the electric current permanently?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current, superconductivity

I thought this question when I learn about the superconductor which has no resistance.

If I made the round wire with the superconductor, I think it is possible for the current to flow through the wire that power consumption is zero. But I don't know that it is possible to flow permanently.

It is right that the round wire made with superconductor has no resistance.
But I think the electron that flows through the wire does an acceleration exercise(circle motion), so it releases the electromagnetic waves.

But I don't know the exact answer. Is it possible to maintain the electric current permanently using the superconductor?

[Is electricity perpetual in a superconductor system?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/364270/)
(I find it, but I think it is not clear answer)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69222/2451

Answer (score 4):

I think the following post-[How can I put a permanent current into a superconducting loop?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/69222/how-can-i-put-a-permanent-current-into-a-superconducting-loop/69223#69223) explains in good detail about what you are asking. In short, it is possible to maintain an electric current in a superconducting loop as long as the loop is superconducting.

Answer (score 0):

> the electron that flows through the wire does an acceleration exercise(circle >motion), so it releases the electromagnetic waves.

No. A constant current, regardless whether it's in a superconductor, in a loop or in a straight wire, corresponds to a constant magnetic field. Check Maxwell equations.

Comment: This answer is correct, but the reasoning is incorrect. Accelerating charges produce radiation, a charge moving in a circle is accelerating. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_formula

Comment: See http://www.hep.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/examples/steadycurrent.pdf

Comment: The question is about currents. The fact that accelerating electrons radiate is irrelevant/misleading.