# Does a battery 'excites' current to flow in a superconductor?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, superconductivity, short-circuits

If yes, how is it possible since a closed circuit with no resistance means 0 voltage, how does the electrons flow initially if there's no potential difference? Any simple explanation or analogy would be very helpful.

Comment: Duplicate [How can I put a permanent current into a superconducting loop](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69222/104696).

Answer (score 0):

Superconducting switches are not simple to make for the very reason that you identified. Typically they will actually make a small segment of the winding resistive by heating it up past the superconducting temperature. Then you can use that small segment of resistive wire to establish a current like normal. Finally, when the current is ramped up to the desired value you remove the heat and let the segment cool below the superconducting temperature. At that point there is no voltage across the segment any more and the current persists.